# Cypress: how to fix a redirect error in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

To test, I need to log in to the site, and then go to the page "page/1". I am doing:

```
describe("[![my first test][1]][1]", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
    const LOGIN = "admin";
    const PASSWORD = "12345";

    cy.visit("/");
    cy.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD);

  });

  it("displaying a page with mok data", () => {

        cy.visit("/page/1");
        //mock redux store
        cy.window()
       .its("store")
       .invoke("dispatch", {
            type: "set_data",
            data: data,
       });
```

but i get error

*AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: [data-test-id=login-input], but never found it. Because this error occurred during a before each hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: my first test*

Need help

*login command*

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login',
  (
    login,
    password,
    status
  ) => {

    cy.intercept("POST", "/login").as("login");

    cy.getByDataTestId("login-input").type(login);
    cy.getByDataTestId("password-input").type(password);

    cy.getByDataTestId("signin-button").click();
  }
);
```

Comment: It's a problem in the custom command *cy.login()*. But the code is not provided.

Comment: please add the code where `[data-test-id=login-input]` is mentioned.

Comment: I add command cy.login()